# python find all file names in folder that follows a pattern

Tags: python

I am trying to find all file names in a folder which follows this pattern: 'index_YYYYMMDD.csv'. The 'YYYYMMDD' part represents the date of the data file. Some of the files names are listed below:

'index_20091101.csv',
'index_20091102.csv',
'index_20091103.csv',
'index_20091104.csv',
'index_20091105.csv',
'index_20091106.csv',
'index_20091107.csv',
'index_20091108.csv',

Given a startDate and endDate, I would like to find all file names, the date part of which is between the startDate and endDate. For example, for the above file list, if the startDate=20091104 and endDate=20091107, the file names I would like to find should be:

'index_20091104.csv',
'index_20091105.csv',
'index_20091106.csv',
'index_20091107.csv'

I've tried os.listdir function, which gives me all the file names. To filter out the unwanted files, I think I need to use regular expression, but could not work it out.

Anyone could help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: Hi all, I figure out a way to solve this problem: [f for f in os.listdir(dataDir) if time.strptime(startDate, "%Y%m%d")<=time.strptime(f[6:14], "%Y%m%d")<=time.strptime(endDate, "%Y%m%d")]. If I am not sure the name pattern applies to all files in folder, I might add 're.match('index_[0-9]*.csv', f)' to it. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take the following approach. You can define a simple file filter factory.

```
import time

def make_time_filter(start, end, time_format, file_format='index_{time_format:}.csv'):
    t_start = time.strptime(start, time_format)
    t_end = time.strptime(end, time_format)
    ft_fmt = file_format.format(time_format=time_format)

    def filt(fname):
        try:
            return t_start <= time.strptime(fname, ft_fmt) <= t_end
        except ValueError:
            return False

    return filt
```

Now, you can simply make a predicate to filter out the date range you want

```
time_filt = make_time_filter('20091101', '20091201', '%Y%m%d')
```

Then pass this to `filter`

```
filter(time_filt, os.listdir(your_dir))
```

Or put it a comprehension of some sort

```
(fname for fname in os.listdir(your_dir) if time_filt(fname))
```

A regex will be more general, but you don't need one in your case since your file names all follow a simple pattern which you know must contain a date.  For more on the `time` module see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html).

Answer (score 17):

```
import glob
glob.glob('index_[0-9]*.csv')
```

This will math the filename that starts with a digital .

[John's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35496842/3994063) solution matches exactly 8 digital .

Comment: Note that these aren't real regex, so "index_2beornot2be.csv" will also match this glob

Comment: @JohnLaRooy oops , I am sorry for that , I thought it's regex .

Comment: Yeah, its a real nasty trap :(

Comment: where is the directory specification?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to match exactly 8 digits with `glob` you need to write them all out like this

```
import glob
glob.glob('index_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].csv')
```

> Help on function glob in module glob:
>
> **glob**(pathname)
>       Return a list of paths matching a pathname pattern.
>
> The pattern may contain simple shell-style wildcards a la
>      fnmatch. However, unlike fnmatch, filenames starting with a
>      dot are special cases that are not matched by '*' and '?'
>      patterns.

If you want real regex, use os.listdir and filter the result

```
[x for x in os.listdir('.') if re.match('index_[0-9]*.csv', x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This will get you where you want to be and allows you to provide start and end dates:

```
import os
import re
import datetime

start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('20071102', '%Y%m%d')
end_date = datetime.datetime.strptime('20071103', '%Y%m%d')

files = os.listdir('.')
files_in_range = []
for fl in files:
    if re.match('index_\d+\.csv', fl):
        date = re.match('index_(\d+)\.csv', fl).group(1)
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
        if date >= start_date and date <= end_date:
            files_in_range.append(fl)

print files_in_range
```